# Python: Installing OmniOrbpy in Windows64(Windows 7) environment

Tags: python, corba, omniorb

I'd like to experiment with a Python (v2.7)  app accessing a CORBA API,  but I keep going around in circles about which OmniOrb pieces are necessary and where they should be placed.

I've downloaded omniORBpy-4.2.0-win64-py27 which I thought should have contained the bits I needed.

Is is as simple as adding the files in the bin\x86_win32 directory into my Python lib\Site-packages directory ?

I've found conflicting information about using the PYTHONPATH environment variable (I don't have one now), is it necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help from Duncan Grisby.

1. The version of omniORBpy must match the Win32/Win64 status of your
   environment.
2. Copy the distribution to a directory (I used python27/lib/site-packages/omniORB
3. Add to or create a PYTHONPATH environment variable that points to ../omniORB/lib/python  and ../omniORB/lib/x86_win32
4. Merge the contents of sample.reg into your Windows Registry
5. Add an explicit PATH environment entry to ../omniORB/bin/x86_win32

Please note that omniORB is case sensitive for the paths, even though Windows is not.